# Domain Name Aliasing in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, dns, domain-name, aliases

Is there way to create short domain name aliases in ubuntu?

I am using ec2 clusters a lot and its tough to keep track of their domain names to login each time.

If there is a way in which i can give custom domain names aliases, it would be great. For example,

ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com --> myserver1

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't create aliases for commands in your shell?  I use tcsh, so in my `.cshrc`:

```
alias   dev     "ssh dev"
```

So you could:

```
alias myserver1 "ssh ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
```

Comment: Or configure nicknames in your ssh config.

Comment: I was looking more on the lines of /etc/hosts.conf.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Elastic IP on AWS and attach that to your AWS instance (I can give you better instructions on how to do it if needed).

Once you have Elastic IP attached to the instance:

- You can obviously SSH to this new IP
- You can create an entry in hosts.conf file to map this ip to any nickname/host name

This is just a summary of what could be done. Please leave me a comment if more specific details are needed.